# Is there a derivation of all possible Bravais lattices in 2D and 3D?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals

Do any of you know a (possibly elegant) derivation of all possible Bravais Lattice and the Crystallographic Group of Lattices in 2 and 3 dimensions? Group theory /abstract nonsense approaches are  welcome.